# How to scale `X` axis and include the data -- Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, curve

I want to plot on X axis the points `[8,16,32,64,128,512]` and on Y axis the corresponding values to these points. I have done the following, but eventhough I have specified the X axis and selected the colum values for it, I am not getting the numbers `[8,16,32,64,128,512]` displayed on X axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `xticks([8 16 32 64 128 256 512])` right after plot (or you may have to get handle of the axe) to set display ticks in X axis

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have put the statement after plot, but it did not work. I am getting the same result. I don't follow your other suggestion which is how to get handle to set display ticks. Can you please explain?

Comment: Sorry, it must be ``xticks``.